# PhoneGap AJAX Login

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am trying to build a log in application in PhoneGap. Ive been looking around a lot for similar things and I found them plenty... but I do not understand why this pieces of code does not work. When i press the logIn_btn it shows that It cannot reach the "success" piece of code. Thank you for your help!

```
 $('#logIn_btn').click(function(){

    user = $('#username').val();
    pass = $('#password').val(); 


     var ev = {'papa':true};

    if(user!='' && pass!=''){
        alert('trying login');
    $.ajax({ 
            url: 'https://localhost/server/IF/mobileApp/login.php',
            type: 'post',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: ev,
            success: function(data){
                alert('asd');       
            }
        });

        console.line('done.')
} else {
    alert('Please insert your username and password.');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server should not be `https://localhost`, it should be the name/ip of the server that you'll be logging into.

For additional information, look at your network tab with Chrome, or install a fail handler

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'https://localhost/server/IF/mobileApp/login.php',
    type: 'post',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: ev,
    success: function(data){
        alert('asd');       
   }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.line`?I think it would be `console.log`. Rather try alerting the message. Also make sure the javascript executes after `deviceready`. Also `localhost` in android is a very different thing. Try using the ipadress or domain name to access the server.